# Decimal value in masm32

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I have a problem with one thing in assembly. I create a variable
`points db 65`. The starting value is 65, but when I want to show this value in program using

```
invoke CreateWindowEx,0,ADDR classStatic,ADDR points, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE,100,100,50,50,hWnd,0,hInstance,0
```

it returns ASCII. In this example, the character "A". How do I fix it to show "65"?

Comment: You need to convert it to text. See for example `snprintf`

Comment: 65 are two chars : '6' and '5'. You can create your own procedure to convert from binary (65) to string ( '65' ).

Answer (score 4):

The `CreateWindowEx` function is expecting a C-style string, which is a pointer to a NUL-terminated sequence of characters.

What you have passed it is actually invalid input, and I'm rather surprised that you got "A" instead of "A$^a!bunch?*of-@(nasty^&+garbage{%". You got lucky that a 0 was placed after your `points` constant, probably because of padding inserted by the assembler.

If you want to display a *number* as the caption of your window, then you will first need to convert that number into a string. There are various ways of doing this. The simplest is just to call a function that will do it for you. Since you're already linking to the Win32 API, you can get away with calling [`wsprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx). Better yet, link to a C runtime library and call `snprintf`. Alternatively, you can write your own code that converts a number to a string.

Assuming that your string is static, an even better approach would be to simply use a string in the first place:

```
points db "65",0
```

(might want to pick a better name than `points`).

---

Also note that Windows is a Unicode-based operating system, and it implements Unicode via a 2-byte UTF-16 type. Therefore, you should always explicitly call the `W`-suffixed versions of Windows API functions (or define the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` symbols), and your string characters will need to be WORD-sized. Therefore, the code would be:

```
strCaption  dw '6','5',0
```

```
invoke CreateWindowExW,0,ADDR classStatic,ADDR strCaption, WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE,100,100,50,50,hWnd,0,hInstance,0
```

Comment: I'am making simple game so i think name `points` is good 65 is only example. Points are starting from 0 and will be changed

Comment: Then you obviously will have to dynamically parse the integer into a string. I suggested three different ways of doing that. The only reason you'd want to reinvent the wheel would be for educational purposes. Otherwise, call a standard function to do it for you.

Comment: Ok, thank you but 'wsprintf' makes in my program syntax error

Comment: I have no idea why. MASM32 definitely supports this function, many people have used it. I can't see your code, so I can't tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: That is not how the function works. You should have read the documentation. You need to pass it a buffer as the first parameter (your buffer is too short---consider allocating space on the stack instead), a format string as the second parameter (in your case, this would be `"%d"`), and `points` as the third parameter.